# How to clear coordinates in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there anyway to reset event.y? I'm creating a game where if I press arrows a widget will move, however whenever I try getting a coordinate it returns the coordinate of the first instance only?

How will I clear event.y so when I press the arrows for a 3rd or 4th time it gives me different y values?

```
def up(event, self):
   print(event.keysym)
   self.y = -15
   ycoord = event.y
   print(ycoord)
```

I have tried del ycoord and del event.y however neither worked.

Comment: First: what do you think ycoord, self.y and event.y all are?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. There is simply not enough information for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

2 problems I notice here:

**First**

Assuming `up` is declared inside a class, the declaration should be:

`def up(self, event)` (event and self have been flipped).

This is because every method which is called on an instance of a class will pass `self` in as the first argument to methods called on it (even `__init__`).

This is why when you ask about clearing it, you're actually getting a dynamic value in the second parameter (misleadingly named self when it is actually the event). This change should get your code working more as expected

**Second**

It seems like you're using `.keysym` and `.y` in the same event handler but these work on different event types (keyboard and mouse respectively).

You mentioned pressing arrow keys so we should note that this event will not include a useful `.y` attribute. Instead you should set some amount for things to move and change y by that each time.

**Code**

```
MOVE_SPEED = 15

def up(self, event):
   print(event.keysym) # Assuming this is the up arrow
   self.y -= MOVE_SPEED
   print(self.y)
```

**NB**
There's a section here about how to use special key identifiers for the arrow keys https://tkinterexamples.com/events/keyboard/keyboard.html#special - alternatively checking `.keysym` works as well.